# When do we not have $|fg|=|f||g|$?

Tags: functions, inequality

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ be two functions. Is it ever the case that $|fg|\ne|f|\cdot|g|$?

What if instead of functions and the standard norm we consider something else, is there a situation where the equality is not true?

Comment: What does $|\cdot|$ mean here?

Comment: just multiplication

Comment: x @Stanislas: No, what does $|\mathit{something}|$ mean?

Comment: Oh it's the euclidian norm (for a fixed x)

Comment: x  @Stanislas: What does that mean? I know a definition of "euclidean norm" $|x|$ when $x$ is an element of $\mathbb R^n$ -- but not when $x$ is a function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: $|f(x)|\equiv|f|$ I just didn't write the x

Comment: is $fg$ composition or multiplication?

Comment: It's multiplication in the example. But the point is to generalize it to other laws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always the case for your particular choice of Euclidean norm. However, considering operator norms like the ones for matrices, they are only **submultiplicative**, i.e. $$||AB|| \leq ||A||| |B||$$ does only hold. Explicitely, one such norm is induced by the Euclidean norm $|\cdot|$ by setting $$||A|| := \sup_{|x| = 1} |Ax|$$

Comment: This is being a bit speculative since $f,g:\mathbb R\mapsto\mathbb R$ is specified.

Comment: @zwim This is related to the second part of the question...namely "...we consider something else..."

Answer (score 1):

For the one-dimensional case, we must have $|fg|=|f|\cdot|g|$ because $|fg|(x)=|(fg)(x)|=|f(x)\cdot g(x)|=|f(x)|\cdot|g(x)|=|f|(x)\cdot|g|(x)$.

Consider now that $f,g:{\bf{R}}^{n}\rightarrow{\bf{R}}^{n}$, then $|f\cdot g|\ne|f|\cdot|g|$, here $\cdot$ is the dot product, because $|f(x)\cdot g(x)|\ne|f(x)|\cdot|g(x)|$ in general, note that $u\cdot v=|u||v|\cos\theta$ for vectors $u,v$ in the two-dimensional case.

Comment: Why don't we have that $|f \cdot g| = |f| \cdot |g|$ in the last case?

Comment: Note that in two-dimensional case, $u=f(x)$, $v=g(x)$ are vectors, $u\cdot v=|u||v|\cos\theta$, here $\theta$ is the angle between them.

Comment: Well, you can define the vector product between geometric vectors (not just in the 2-dimensional case) as $\vec{v} \cdot \vec{u}:=|\vec{v}||\vec{u}|\cos(\theta)$. And if you represent those vectors in the ordinary orthonormal base, you get $\underline{v}$ and $\underline{u}$, and you have that $\underline{v} \cdot \underline{u}=v_k u_k$, where $u_k$ and $v_k$ are the components of the vectors. In your case, $f$ and $g$ are $n$ dimensional vectors, and $|f|$ and $|g|$ are 1 dimensional vectors. So you can say that $|f \cdot g|=|f| \cdot |g|$, I think.

Comment: I am little confused, can you demonstrate an example? And $|\cdot|$ here is the $\sqrt{(\cdot)^{2}+(\cdot)^{2}}$ thing.

Comment: Which part was the confusing?

Comment: So if I have $u=(1,2)$, $v=(3,4)$, then $u\cdot v=3+8=11$ and $|u|=\sqrt{5}$, $|v|=5$ so $u\cdot v\ne|u||v|$, why there is an equality here. And the orthonormal basis would be $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$.

Comment: You are totally right in that, I must be too tired. But the $u \cdot v = |u| |v| \cos(\theta)$ holds for all $n$, not just for $2$.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your reminding.